# Rails: add questions to poll

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my Rails app I have poll and questions which user can add to poll. I can create poll and question separately, but how can I add created question to poll?

poll.rb

```
class Poll < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :questions

end
```

question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :poll

end
```

polls_controller.rb

```
class PollsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @poll = Poll.new
  end

  def create
    @poll = Poll.create(poll_params)
    if @poll.save
      redirect_to poll_path(@poll)
      flash[:succsess] = "Poll created!"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

    private

      def poll_params
        params.require(:poll).permit(:name)
      end

end
```

questions_controller.rb

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @question = Question.new
    @poll = Poll.find(params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @question = Question.create(question_params)
    @poll.questions << @question
    if @question.save
      flash[:succsess] = "Question created"
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

    def question_params
      params.require(:question).permit(:title, :comment)
    end

end
```

Comment: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Poll model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :questions
```

In your html:

```
<%= form_for @poll do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %>
    <%= render "question_fields", :f => builder %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Submit" %></p>
<% end %>
```

In your PollsController:

```
def poll_params
  params.require(:poll).permit(:name, :question_fields => [:name, etc...])
end
```

Have a look: http://www.sitepoint.com/complex-rails-forms-with-nested-attributes/